# How to create category for each page on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to create 2 pages Dogs and Cats using Wordpress.
At the Dogs page , I want to create category to show Dogs name and at the Cats page , I want to create category to show Cats name. So , How to do that . Please help me to resolve it.

Thanks
Nguyen

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. I'll get you started, but there's a reasonable amount for you to cover.

Create two post categories, one for Dogs and one for Cats.  Add your posts about dogs and cats to each of those categories.

You create two pages, Dogs and Cats.

You create two custom page templates, one for Dogs and one for Cats and you apply them to the relevant pages;

http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Custom_Page_Templates

In each custom template you set up a custom loop.  So in the Dogs custom template your loop will be for all the Dogs posts, and for Cats you pull in the Cats posts.

To do this you use `WP_Query` with the `cat` parameter as an argument.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

Good luck!